# How to make is_admin() return false when I need it to?

Tags: plugins

I am using a plugin to display a Terms and Conditions page to my visitors. The visitors would have to agree to the terms and conditions in order to see the actual content of the website.

When this plugin is active and the terms and conditions page is displayed, it does not use the normal theme rendering flow. Instead, the plugin calls get_header(), get_footer(), etc to render the page directly. While doing so, is_admin() would return true, even though we really should consider the terms and conditions page to be the front-end and not the dashboard/admin panel. The theme uses is_admin() to decide whether or not to enqueue certain javascripts, so it enqueues the wrong set of javascript files and I get a whole bunch of javascript errors.

How can I make is_admin() return true in the context of the plugin?

P.S. The exact plugin in question is this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/force-apply-terms-and-conditions/

Comment: Please show the code. Or is it from the plugin?

Comment: It's from the plugin. The plugin defines a plugin_force_apply class, which has a show_confirm() function that does the rendering.
And you would need a theme that depends on is_admin() to enqueue CSS or javascript, in order to demonstrate the effect.

Comment: Afaik, that isn't your problem. The plugin clearly hooks to `init`, which is present everywhere in WP. Also take a look at the first 2 lines of code in `force-apply-terms-and-conditions.php` -this tells us, that if we're not in admin, it hooks nicely.

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda tricky! I'd say use either of the conditional tags or the `global $pagenow` variable to check your page, and then do that action what you'd otherwise do if `is_admin` was false.